# why python is dropping errors after execution is being completed

Tags: python, file-handling, shutil, python-os

I write the program that penetrate inside the folder and check if folder have sub folders that either contained files or not if there is folders which contained files inside program penetrate into it again and delete all founded files in order to make folders empty and get ready to remove it but after the program being executed i get the following error when there is many folders and files inside the directory

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'FileLocation\\Folder'
```

and if the directory name inside that directory has two or more words with space separator between them the program runs well but drop the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'FileLocation\\firstName secondName'
```

and the codes which I wrote with the only **os module** are the one that follows

```
import os

# parent folder
New = "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\New"

# check if the path exists
if os.path.exists(New):
# looping over all files and directories inside the parent folder
for files in os.listdir(New):
    # check if there is directories
    if os.path.isdir(New + '\\' + files):
        # check if the directories are empty and get ready to remove it
        if len(os.listdir(New + '\\' + files)) <= 0:
            os.rmdir(New + '\\' + files)
        # when directories are not empty
        else:
            # search for file inside the nested directories
            for sub_files in os.listdir(New + '\\' + files):
                # remove all the files inside the nested directories
                os.remove(New + '\\' + files + "\\" + sub_files)
        # remove directories after removing files inside it
        os.removedirs(New + '\\' + files)
    # check if there is files
    if os.path.isfile(New + '\\' + files):
        # removing the files inside the parent folder
        os.remove(New + '\\' + files)
# removing the entire folder after deleting all files and folders inside it
os.rmdir(New)
else:
    print('Folder doesn\'t exist')
```

while when i wrote the program like the second following codes work well without any logic or runtime error and its codes are the following with the **shutil and os modules**

```
import shutil
import os

# parent folder
New = "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\New"
if os.path.exists(New):
     shutil.rmtree(New)
else:
    print('Folder doesn\'t exist')
```

so i would like to know if there is any further configuration about the python errors or any bugs in my codes to fix or any way drops no error at runtime which will be better for this(removing directories which is not empty) thanks

Comment: I just wanted to delete the nested directory by using the first method but sometimes went wrong and i don't why if it is the bug in my or poor configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's this part:

```
    if len(os.listdir(New + '\\' + files)) <= 0:
        os.rmdir(New + '\\' + files)
    # when directories are not empty
    else:
        # search for file inside the nested directories
        for sub_files in os.listdir(New + '\\' + files):
            # remove all the files inside the nested directories
            os.remove(New + '\\' + files + "\\" + sub_files)
```

You have `if len(os.listdir(New + '\\' + files)) <= 0:` which means if the folder is empty. 
You also have `else:`, which is for non-empty folders. 
But, if in that folder, there is another folder that is also not empty, 
you cannot call `os.remove(New + '\\' + files + "\\" + sub_files)` on that, 
so it throws a `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied` error.

Answer (score 1):

Click right button on Pychrarm or CMD whatever you use to run the script and select Run as a System administrator

Comment: i always run an editor as an administrator, I guess that's not the problem